# Nuances of「すらさえも」?

Tags: nuances, particles

I came across this 「すらさえも」construction in the following sentence:

> 「子供を誘拐したロリコン野郎から**すらさえも**バカにされ続けた」

I've learned that they mean (mostly) the same, but haven't come across them in immediate succession; therefore I'd like to if there are any special nuances to the use of 「**すら**」and 「**さえ**」in combination?

Comment: Although you can find a few examples of すらさえ in lyrics and such, BCCWJ has zero example of it. I personally feel this may just be a typo. Unless you are writing something creative or poetic, you should not use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

「すらさえも」 is only a highly emphatic form of:

・「すら（も）」 or

・「さえ（も）」

Combining the two does not produce a "new" meaning of its own.
You should, therefore, just think of it as an emphatic way of saying "even" in English.

> "Even the lolicon bastard who (had) kidnapped a kid kept making fun of me, too."

The original sentence is in the passive-voice form while my own TL, in the active voice.